# Compressed sensing using matlab

Tags: matlab, image-compression

I am trying to implement compressed-sensing technique using matlab to reconstruct an image from fewer measurements.

What I've done so far is dividing the image into 8-by-8 blocks, then multiply each block by sensing matrix PHI which is Gaussian random matrix, after that decode the compressed blocks using CVX or L1 Magic.

The problem is that I don't get good results, so can someone help me please ?

example code

```
x=imread('greyscale_image.tiff');
x=im2double(x);
x_1blk=x(1:8,1:8);
xdct=dct2(x_1blk);
xq=xdct/quanMTX;
xq=reshape(xq,[],1);
y=phi*xq;

x0=phi.'*y;
tic
s1=l1eq_pd(x0, phi, [], y,1e-3);
toc
s1=reshape(s1,8,8);
s1=s1*quantMTX;
s1=idct2(s1);
```

I get around 25.000 for psnr, while I am expecting to get around 29.000

Comment: 1) Post your current code that reproduces your problem. See: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 2) Explain what results you are expecting and how your current results are different.

Comment: Ok, I've edited my post to include what you asked for

Comment: It somewhat depends on the image you are using, if you are expecting around 29.000 psnr, how is this calculated - or based on which examples. If you are using the data as the estimated 29.000 psnr and only got 25.000 I would suggest looking into the Gaussian random matrix (did you normalize this?)

Comment: this is my phi

phi=randn(p,64);
phi=orth(phi');
phi=phi';

@GameOfThrows